# Roth IRA all in one fund, or not?

Tags: united-states, ira, mutual-funds, diversification

All the money in my Roth IRA is in FFFFX.  I'm making my yearly deposit.  Is there any reason not to put it in the same fund?  To put it another way, do I need to diversify my Roth IRA (or is that the objective of this fund, so it's enough)?

Comment: How much are we talking about?

Comment: @PeteB. - I put in my max every year (5.5k)

Comment: While many financially literate people find target date fund suspect (they have no benchmark, so how would we know if they are doing the right thing?), in principle they are designed to be your one-and-only fund.  If you believe the fund's claims, you need not diversify further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you could very well leave it in something like FFFFX, which for readers is a self balancing fund with a target retirement date of 2040.  These funds are a conglomeration of other funds that tend to move more conservatively as time passes.

However, I like to put no more than 10% of my portfolio in one fund with exceptions made for balances less than 20K.   So If I had 18K it really wouldn't matter if it was in FUSEX a S&P 500 index fund.  However by investing in FFFFX you pretty much meet that requirement.

So you are golden if that fund meets your goals.  For me, I kind of hate bonds and despite being of similar age, I have almost no money invested in bonds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Another thing is, I'm no longer with Fidelity - just the fund is left over from when I moved my IRA to my new bank.  My bank has tried to get me to switch to their fund before (target retirement fund, or whatever it's called).  Would there be any logic in doing that?

Comment: No particular logic in changing funds unless you are getting charged to make deposits to FFFFX.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should diversify your portfolio.  If your entire portfolio is in the Roth IRA, then you should eventually diversify that.  However, if you have an IRA and a 401k, then it's perfectly fine for the IRA to be in a single fund.  For example, I used my IRA to buy a riskier REIT that my 401k doesn't support.

Second, if you only have a small amount currently invested, e.g. $5500, it may make sense to put everything in a single fund until you have enough to get past the low balance fees.  It's not uncommon for funds to charge lower fees to someone who has $8000, $10,000, or $12,000 invested.  Note that if you deposit $10,000 and the fund loses money, they'll usually charge you the rate for less than $10,000.  So try to exceed the minimum with a decent cushion.

A balanced fund may make sense as a first fund.  That way they handle the diversification for you.  A targeted fund is a special kind of balanced fund that changes the balance over time.  Some have reported that targeted funds charge higher fees.  Commissions on those higher fees may explain why your bank wants you to buy.

I personally don't like the asset mixes that I've seen from targeted funds.  They often change the stock/bond ratio, which is not really correct.  The stock/bond ratio should stay the same.  It's the securities (stocks and bonds) to monetary equivalents that should change, and that only starting five to ten years before retirement.  Prior to that the only reason to put money into monetary equivalents is to provide time to pick the right securities fund.  Retirees should maintain about a five year cushion in monetary equivalents so as not to be forced to sell into a bad market.

Long term, I'd prefer low-load index funds.  A bond fund and two or three stock funds.  You might want to build your balance first though.  It doesn't really make sense to have a separate fund until you have enough money to get the best fees.  70-75% stocks and 25-30% bonds (should add to 100%, e.g. 73% and 27%).  Balance annually when you make your new deposit.

Comment: "Diversify your portfolio" seems like very strange advice given they have their money in a balanced fund. Those are, inherently made up of funds over a large amount of funds.

Comment: @Fomite  The question was essentially "Should I diversify my IRA?"  My point was that it's not the IRA that needs diversifying, but the portfolio overall.  I covered how a balanced fund relates to diversification in the third paragraph.  Perhaps read past the first sentence next time?

Comment: I did. I still think it's odd and at best tangental advice.